# Could not console log the updated state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a simple application where the user can create a new form on a button click, so for this, I have an array state like this :

```
const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([0]);
const [count, setCount] = useState([0]);
```

And on my button onClick method I have this,

```
setCount(count + 1);
setNumbers(numbers.concat(numbers[0] + count));
```

In my render method, I have :

```
{numbers.map((number) => {
      return (
        <div key={number}>
          <InputCreator id={number} value={number} />
        </div>
      );
    })}
```

And my InputCreator component is a simple callback component with few textfields.

So far, it works well. Lately I wanted to add a delete functionality where the user can delete that particular form. So, I added.a button inside this form and on the onClick method, I tried console loging the "numbers" state to check everything is working, but it logs only the default value I have given while creating the state and not the updated state. What could be the reason ? So my idea is to delete that index from the array using the props passed, so that the component will re-render with the updated number of forms. Is there a better way to do this ?

EDIT : This is my InputCreator component,

```
const InputCreator = useCallback((props) => {
const { id, value } = props;
// console.log(titles[id]);
return (
  <div>
    <Col xs={12} md={8}>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <Form
          noValidate
          validated={false}
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          encType="multipart/form-data"
        >
          <Form.Group controlId="formGroupTitle">
            <Form.Label>Title</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              placeholder="Title"
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, value)}
              name="title"
              value={titles[id]}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group controlId="formGroupTitle">
            <Form.Label>Description</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              name="description"
              placeholder="Max limit 30"
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, value)}
              maxLength={31}
              value={descriptions[id]}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Button
          variant="outline-primary"
          size="sm"
          className={styles.deleteBtn}
          onClick={(e) => handleDelete(e, number)}
          >
          X
          </Button>
          </Form>
          )})
```

handleDelete :

```
const handleDelete = (e, value) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(numbers);
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the console log in your code. So it can be clear, where you are trying to log the state

Comment: @ManishSundriyal I have added the code as per your suggestion, please do check.

Comment: Inside `handleDelete`,
Are you sure about `console.log(numbers);` ? it should be `console.log(value);` right?

Comment: `numbers` is the global state which I want to access. I have found out that the problem is that, I am trying to access the state from a function which has a callback hook, so I could'nt access it, Is there any way I could ?

Comment: I am sure not why you cannot access it. If you want to remove that index from the numbers array then find and delete it. Let me know if I am missing something or update the question with any extra detail.

Answer (score 0):

I will just point out the mistakes I see as your question is not worded clearly.

Keys aren't passed into  they are passed into list in order to create a list for every element with a unique ID. I am not sure what you are trying to do in your render method but I would suggest doing something like this :

```
const renderNumbers = () => myArray.map((number, index) =>
  <MyComponent key={index} number={number} />
```

To delete an element. Create a function that takes in the ID. Filter it to show a new array without that ID, below is an example that you ca apply.

```
const deletePerson = (id) => {
    setNumbers(numbers.filter((number) => number.id !== id));
  };
```

Send this handle to the button that deletes the element

```
const handleDeleteNumber = () => {
    deleteNumber(number.id);
  };
```

Make a single handleInputChange() that you can use for all input changes. Such as this one :

```
const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setInfo({ ...info, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };
```

In the  tag you pass in id and values separately like this

```
value={descriptions}
key={id}
```